# How can I center a floated input element vertically in a fixed div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a simple Webshop and I need help with centering the input elements in the top div.

**HTML/CSS**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lightcyan;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.top img {
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.top h1 {
  float: left;
}

.top form {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}

.top form input {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webshop</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <img src="ImageUsed.png">
    <h1>Webshop Title</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="submit" value="register">
      <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The `div`, aswell as the `img` and `h1` elements look good, but I want the two `input` elements inside the `form` element to be centered vertically inside the `div` element. Any Idea how I can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I vertically align elements in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-can-i-vertically-align-elements-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

Remove all floats as they are not needed when using flex. Set `flex` to both `top` and your `<form>` then use `align-items: center;`.

I also added another `div` to nest your `img` and `h1` in and flexed that so `space-between` on `top` pairs them next to each other.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lightcyan;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.top img {
  width: 80px;
}

form,
.top > div:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.top form {
  height: 100%;
}

.top form input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webshop</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
  <div>
    <img src="ImageUsed.png">
    <h1>Webshop Title</h1>
  </div>
    <form>
      <input type="submit" value="register">
      <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use floats. Use flexbox instead which is what you want to arrange elements in one axis.

```css
<style>
    body{
    margin: 0;
    background: lightcyan;
  }
  .top{
    position: fixed;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .top h1{
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .top form input{
   display: block;
   float: right;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Webshop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <img src="ImageUsed.png">
      <h1>Webshop Title</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="submit" value="register">
        <input type="submit" value="login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes that is what i am telling

Comment: In most of cases, grid and flexboxes are used efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

By using flexbox, it becomes more easy

```
.top {
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a fixed `height` and `position: relative` to your fixed-position header (which I would recommend anyway), you can use the following method for the parent element of those input elements, which uses `position: absolute;`, `top: 50%` and `translateY(-50%)` to center that element vertically in its parent, and `right: 0` instead of `float: right` to align it right:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    background: lightcyan;
  }
  .top{
    position: fixed;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .top img{
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
  }
  .top h1{
    float: left;
  }
  .top form{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .top form input{
    display: block;
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Webshop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <img src="ImageUsed.png">
      <h1>Webshop Title</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="submit" value="register">
        <input type="submit" value="login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```